# Where to change assemblyinformation-defaults?

Tags: visual-studio, assemblyinfo

our system-administrator has installed visual studio 2008 on my pc and didn't enter our companys name. Now i have the problem, that I always have to change the name in the assembly-information manually, because the pc-manufacturer is automatically inserted to the assembly-informations. Does anybody know where I can change the default-values for the assemblyinformations in visual-studio, because I alway forget to change the company and copyright value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vssetup/thread/f225f113-98bb-4c2e-b605-b831b61c088d). This will help you set the company name attribute permanently via registry.

Answer: Set the value of the registry key for `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization` For 64 bit OS, the registry key is `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization`

Comment: Do not only give a link as an answer. Answer:

Set the value of the registry key for 
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization


 For 64 bit OS, the registry key is 
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization